# Sphinx' math directive not working

Tags: python-sphinx, mathjax

I am trying to display math in my Sphinx documentation. In `conf.py` I added `sphinx.ext.mathjax`

```python
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx.ext.graphviz',
    'sphinx.ext.mathjax',
    'rst2pdf.pdfbuilder',
]
```

In my `.rst` files (so not in docstrings in python code), I add (straight from the docs):

```rst
Since Pythagoras, we know that :math:`a^2 + b^2 = c^2`.

.. math::

   (a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2

   (a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2
```

The output is not styled. Looking at the source html, I see:

```html
<div class="section" id="view-angle-and-orientation">

<p>Since Pythagoras, we know that a^2 + b^2 = c^2.</p>
(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2

(a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2</div>
```

So the `math` directive doesn't insert the necessary `$$` and `\( \)` for mathjax (nor is there a `<span class="math">` tag). When I insert those myself in the rst, it works.

How can I get the math extension to work?